# Convert html table to have column filters

Tags: javascript, python, html

Looking to convert a simple HTML table to one that supports column filters with the least amount of code and library integration. Project is using flask-admin. 
This is the closest thing I found, but it requires node.js and grunt. 
https://github.com/koalyptus/TableFilter
Any other simple libraries available?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use bootsrap tables.You can filter, sort, search and a lot of things on the table
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/sort/
You can use them from client and server side.

Comment: This doesn't support per column filtering.